# Google Form select radio button with js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select radio buttons randomly on a google form. I tried browsing the web for a working script but none of them are working. I tried to make my own but I'm always getting that error:

> `Cannot read property 'click' of undefined.`

Firstly I do a:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer');
```

to get all parts of the form. It returns the correct amount of parts. Then I do an

```
item.querySelectorAll(".appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupOffRadio");
```

to get all of the radio buttons in that part and it returns the correct amount of radio buttons.

After that I randomly pick one and perform `.click()` on it but it gives me that error. Even if I *querySelect* anything else it's still doesn't works.

Any idea how to fix that or google made it impossible to manipulate it's forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the underlying HTML of the radio buttons in a google form, I was able to isolate each of the radio buttons using all these classes together, so:

```
var allRadioButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupElContainer.exportContainerEl.docssharedWizToggleLabeledControl.freebirdThemedRadio.freebirdThemedRadioDarkerDisabled");
var numberOfRadioButtons = allRadioButtons.length;
function randomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
}
var randomRadioButtonNumberToSelect = randomNumber(0, numberOfRadioButtons);
allRadioButtons[randomRadioButtonNumberToSelect].click();
```

works for me.

This of course only works for one question in a google form, you would have to do some more manipulation to work with multiple questions, I would suggest first finding an array of questions, and then for each question selecting the radio buttons that are a child of that question at random, and then moving on to the next question